# Newton's law of cooling, why true?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

Why in Newton's law of cooling the heat loss is proportional to the difference of tempretures. I mean how we know it is true? Why is it not $$\frac{dT}{dt}=-kt(T-T_a)$$ (linearly dependent on $t$) for instance? For example I can prove fundamental theorem of calculus so I know it is true but how do I know Newton's law of cooling is true?

Comment: The way we know it's true is by experiment, as with other "laws" in physics. There are several ways to see a linear time dependence doesn't make sense. What happens when $t$ is very large? When $t<0$?

Comment: Newtons law of cooling is an approximation that applies under certain specific circumstances.

Comment: It's a bad approximation to most of more realistic cooling laws, but it is simple, and it has analytic solutions. Hence it is used widely in physics. Simplicity often wins over accuracy in modeling first steps, the argument being "you have to start somewhere".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do we know that the Law of Cooling is true?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/174740/how-do-we-know-that-the-law-of-cooling-is-true). See also https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/178346/226902

Comment: It is not 'true' so much as the simplest reasonable estimate one might suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that the cooling rate is some uknnown function $f(\Delta T)$ of the the temperature difference $\Delta T$ between the system and the cooling source, i.e.,
$$
   \frac{dT}{dt} = f(\Delta T)
$$
Express $f$ in Taylor series about $\Delta T=0$:
$$
   \frac{dT}{dt} =  f_0 + f_1 \Delta T + f_2 \Delta T^2 + \cdots
$$
where $f_i$ are constants. At $\Delta T=0$ we must have $dT/dt=0$, therefore $f_0$. The cooling law becomes
$$
   \frac{dT}{dt} =  f_1 \Delta T + f_2 \Delta T^2 + \cdots
$$

For small $\Delta T$ this can be truncated to
$$ 
   \frac{dT}{dt} =  f_1 \Delta T 
$$
which is Newton's law.

For small enough $\Delta T$ Newton's law is *always* true. For large enough $\Delta T$ it breaks down. What is "small enough" or "large enough" depends on the particular system.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, Newton's law of cooling is that the rate at which the body loses thermal energy $\dot Q$ to its environment is proportional to a function $f(x)$ of the difference $x=T-T_a$ between the temperature of the body $T$ and the temperature of its environment $T_a$. When $x=0$ then there is no thermal exchange between the body and its environment, so that $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)\approx -k_0x$+....

For a small temperature difference we can approximate $f$ with a linear function, so that we have $\dot Q = -k_0(T-T_a)$. When the body's caloric equation of state is given as $\delta Q = C_p dT$ then for small enough rates we have $\dot Q = C_p \frac{dT}{dt}$ and get the formula $\frac{dT}{dt}=-\frac{k_0}{C_p}(T-T_a)$. In general $C_p$ can be a function of $T$.

It is conceivable that you have a body for which $C_p$ is explicitly *time-dependent*. This can happen when, for example, $C_p=g_1(T,p)$ or $C_p=g_2(T,V)$. In either case by externally controlling the *other*, ie., $p=p(t)$ or $V=V(t)$ mechanical parameter you may get a time dependent heat capacity beyond the more usual temperature only dependent case.

Answer (score 1):

We should be clear that Newton's law is not a law, or at least not a law that embodies any fundamental principle. It is just an empirical observation that the rate of heat flow is approximately proportional to the temperature difference in situations where the cooling is dominated by convection.

The cooling process is complicated, but if you are happy with a plausibility argument rather than a derivation we can do this as follows. Consider this diagram showing a surface being cooled by convection:

[image: Cooling]

When air is flowing past any surface there is always a thin layer in which the air is stationary. This is the [boundary layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_layer). Within this layer heat flows by conduction. Then farther from the surface we assume the air flow is fast enough to keep the temperature approximately equal to the ambient temperature. So across the boundary layer the temperature falls from the temperature of the solid $T_1$ to the ambient temperature $T_0$, and we get a temperature gradient:

$$ \frac{dT}{dx} = \frac{T_1 - T_0}{\ell} $$

Then [Fourier's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_conduction#Fourier%27s_law) tells us that the rate of heat flow is proportional to the temperature gradient:

$$ \frac{dq}{dt} \propto \frac{dT}{dx} = k(T_1 - T_0) $$

for some constant $k$ and we get Newton's law of cooling.

Answer (score 0):

Newton's law of cooling is an empirical relationship found to agree with experimental results for heat transfer between the surface of a solid and a flowing fluid, where the complexities of the actual conduction/convection process are "rolled up" into a heat transfer coefficient which is experimentally determined.

Specifically, Newton's law of cooling is $dQ = h \enspace dA\enspace \Delta T$ where $dQ$ is the local rate of heat transfer though a surface area $dA$, $h$ is the heat transfer coefficient, and $\Delta T = T_s - T_f$; $T_s$ the temperature of the solid surface and $T_f$ the bulk temperature of the flowing fluid.

For more details see the classic textbook Heat Transmission by McAdams.